# How to make validation of the form?

Tags: javascript, validation

I create validation for the form.
If the second field is filled, and the first field is empty - the submit button is activated

[image]

My code - https://jsfiddle.net/wogdfb3k/

```js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  function init(form) {

    const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('.form__input');
    const inputName = form.querySelector('.form__input--name');
    const submit = form.querySelector('.form__submit');

    function generateErrors(text) {
      let error = document.createElement('div');
      error.classList.add('form__error');
      error.textContent = text;

      return error;
    }

    function removeErrors() {
      const errors = form.querySelectorAll('.form__error');
      for (let i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
        if (errors[i] > 0) {
          submit.setAttribute('disabled', true);
        }
        errors[i].remove();
      }

    }

    function checkFieldsEmpty() {
      for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

        if (!inputs[i].value) {
          const error = generateErrors('This is a required field');
          inputs[i].parentElement.insertBefore(error, inputs[i].nextSibling);
          submit.setAttribute('disabled', true);
        } else if (inputs[i].value.length < 3 || inputs[i].value.length > 40) {
          const error = generateErrors('3 to 40 characters');
          inputs[i].parentElement.insertBefore(error, inputs[i].nextSibling);

          submit.setAttribute('disabled', true);

        } else {
          submit.removeAttribute('disabled');
        }
      }
    }

    function validate(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      removeErrors();
      checkFieldsEmpty();
    }

    form.addEventListener('input', validate);
    form.addEventListener('submit', validate);
  }

  const forms = document.querySelectorAll(".form");
  forms.forEach(init);


})();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.form__input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.form__input+.form__input {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.form__submit {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.form__error {
  color: #f00;
  margin: 5px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="form">
  <input type="text" class="form__input form__input--1" placeholder="Input 1">
  <input type="text" class="form__input form__input--2" placeholder="Input 2">
  <button class="form__submit" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>

<form action="#" class="form">
  <input type="text" class="form__input form__input--1" placeholder="Input 1">
  <input type="text" class="form__input form__input--2" placeholder="Input 2">
  <button class="form__submit" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Problem code

```
function checkFieldsEmpty() {
            for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

                if (!inputs[i].value) {
                    const error = generateErrors('Это обязательное поле');
                    inputs[i].parentElement.insertBefore(error, inputs[i].nextSibling);                
                    submit.setAttribute('disabled', true);
                } 

                else if (inputs[i].value.length < 3 || inputs[i].value.length > 40) {
                    const error = generateErrors('От 3 до 40 символов');
                    inputs[i].parentElement.insertBefore(error, inputs[i].nextSibling);

                    submit.setAttribute('disabled', true);

                } 

                else{
                    submit.removeAttribute('disabled');
                }
            }
        }
```

I expect that the button will be active for all fields of the form, but in fact it turns out the button becomes active when filling in the second field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adapt your `checkFieldsEmpty` function slightly so it removes the disabled attribute after all fields are checked and only if all tests passed, something like that:

```
        function checkFieldsEmpty() {
            let disabled = false;
            for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if (!inputs[i].value) {
                    const error = generateErrors('This is a required field');
                    inputs[i].parentElement.insertBefore(error, inputs[i].nextSibling);
                    disabled = true;
                } else if (inputs[i].value.length < 3 || inputs[i].value.length > 40) {
                    const error = generateErrors('3 to 40 characters');
                    inputs[i].parentElement.insertBefore(error, inputs[i].nextSibling);
                    disabled = true;
                }
            }
            if(!disabled) {
                submit.removeAttribute('disabled');
            };
        }
```